# Create threads only if same thread name does'nt exist as active thread (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading

How to only create threads assigned with name, such that same name threads are not active?
For eg.:

```
threading.Thread(name='t1', target=foo).start() 
threading.Thread(name='t1', target=foo).start()
```

Here, since already thread named t1 is running, the second t1 should be cancelled. It is to avoid redundant threads performing the same task. But, once the first t1 dies, and another thread with same names i.e. 't1' arrives, then it should run.
The constraints are: 10+ threads may try to generate. Thread Name are generated using random.randint(1,10). So, I need to check during runtime only with the thread name.

Here is my code:

```
import logging
import time
import threading
import random

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='[%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s', )

e = threading.Event()
Thread_list = ['default']

def worker():
    logging.info('Starting')
    time.sleep(3)
    logging.info('Ending')
    try:
        Thread_list.remove(threading.currentThread().getName())
    except:
        pass
    return

def application_manager(appId):
    #print threading.enumerate()
    event_is_set = e.wait(2)
    if event_is_set:
        th = threading.Thread(name=appId, target=worker)
        Thread_list.append(threading.currentThread().getName())
        th.start()
    else:
        logging.warning('Task already running.')

def subsystem_request():
    for i in range(10):
        appId = random.randint(1,10)
        application_manager(appId)

def fdir():
    logging.debug('FDIR')
    count = 0
    cur = threading.currentThread()
    time.sleep(2)
    for fd in range(5):
        e.clear()
        for t in threading.enumerate():
            for u in threading.enumerate():
                if t.getName() == cur:
                    e.set()
                elif (t.getName() in u.getName()) and (t.getName() != 'MainThread'):
                    e.clear()
                else:
                    e.set()


fdir_thread = threading.Thread(name='fdir_thread', target=fdir)
fdir_thread.setDaemon(True)
fdir_thread.start()
subsystem_request()

fdir_thread.join()
```

**Actual output:**

```
[DEBUG] (fdir_thread) FDIR
[WARNING] (MainThread) Task already running.
[WARNING] (MainThread) Task already running.
[WARNING] (MainThread) Task already running.
[WARNING] (MainThread) Task already running.
[WARNING] (MainThread) Task already running.
[WARNING] (MainThread) Task already running.
[WARNING] (MainThread) Task already running.
[WARNING] (MainThread) Task already running.
[WARNING] (MainThread) Task already running.
[WARNING] (MainThread) Task already running.
```

**Another actual output:**

```
[INFO] (9         ) Starting
[INFO] (7         ) Starting
[INFO] (1         ) Starting
[INFO] (9         ) Starting     //This thread should be cancelled  
[INFO] (4         ) Starting
[INFO] (10        ) Starting
[INFO] (2         ) Starting
[INFO] (7         ) Starting     //This thread should be cancelled  
[INFO] (5         ) Starting
[INFO] (8         ) Starting
[INFO] (9         ) Ending
[INFO] (1         ) Ending
[INFO] (7         ) Ending
[INFO] (9         ) Ending
[INFO] (2         ) Ending
[INFO] (10        ) Ending
[INFO] (4         ) Ending
[INFO] (7         ) Ending
[INFO] (5         ) Ending
[INFO] (8         ) Ending
```

**Expected output:**

```
[INFO] (9         ) Starting
[INFO] (7         ) Starting
[INFO] (1         ) Starting
[INFO] (4         ) Starting
[INFO] (10        ) Starting
[INFO] (2         ) Starting
[INFO] (5         ) Starting
[INFO] (8         ) Starting
[INFO] (9         ) Ending
[INFO] (1         ) Ending
[INFO] (7         ) Ending
[INFO] (2         ) Ending
[INFO] (10        ) Ending
[INFO] (4         ) Ending
[INFO] (5         ) Ending
[INFO] (8         ) Ending
```

Each of these active threads have unique name during.
I am using threading.Event(). So, function application_manager waits for 2 secs and func fdir() checks using threading.enumerate() for same name, if yes, then e.clear() else, e.set(). Once, e.set(), application_manager() will create the thread.

**I want to use fdir() to check and then communicate to application_manager() for thread generation or cancellation.

NOTE: fdir() and application_manager() should be 2 different threads.**

Comment: This sounds like a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to make a program such that it will only create threads with unique name when compared to names of active threads. @AsadSaeeduddin

Comment: Surely that is not the "purpose" of the program? That's what @AsadSaeeduddin implied. It rather seems you should rework (describe) the logic that creates the threads in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem using global list which stores appId and instead of checking from the active threads, check from the list and once the thread dies, it is removed from the list, though couldn't use threading.Event() as desired, for communication between threads.

```
import logging
import time
import threading
import random

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='[%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)s) %(message)s', )

name_check = []

def worker():
    logging.info('Starting to process')
    time.sleep(3)
    logging.info('Ending')
    return

def application_manager(appId):
    name_ID="appId-"+str(appId)
    if name_ID in name_check:
        logging.warning('Task already running.')
        threading.Thread(name=fdir, target=fdir).start()
    else:
        th = threading.Thread(name=name_ID, target=worker)
        th.start()
    name_check.append(name_ID)

def subsystem_request():
    for i in range(10):
        appId = random.randint(1,10)
        application_manager(appId)

def fdir():
    logging.debug('Task cancelled')
    return  

subsystem_request()
```

Comment: Use a set() instead of list to improve lookup speed

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to refactor your code to use a [Lock](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects) object

```
t1 = threading.Lock()

def foo(*args):
    if not t1.acquire(wait=False):
         return

    # do stuff
```

While this does exactly what you describe - i.e. if somehting else holds the lock the execution will be "cancelled" you are probably better off refactoring to avoid calling the thread altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the thread.is_alive() function.

```
    if t1.is_alive() == 0:
        threading.Thread(name='t1', target=foo).start()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

EDIT:

Using:

```
    texists = 0
    for t in threads:
        if t.name() == 't1':
            texists = 1
```

You can check if it exists then use an if statement to make it if it doesn't.

Comment: here, t1 is a thread object name. I need to check wrt thread name.
The problem is, th is not defined for the first time.

`code  
if th.is_alive() == 0 and th.getName() != appId:  
  th = threading.Thread(name=appId, target=worker)  
  th.start()
`

Comment: I am using random.randint(1,10), so I have to access t.name() during runtime and check with all active thread names which keeps on changing.